# Java EE: Does implementation of Java EE 7 use native code?

Tags: jakarta-ee

Obviously java SE is implemented a lot native and a lot in java itself.
I'm curious is java EE implemented just over java SE in java,
or does it have native calls itself?

Comment: I would guess the spec doesnt say that everything has to be in one way or another as long as the implementation is fulfilling the contracts of the specification.

Comment: Java EE is a specification. There are many implementations of it. All the ones I know are pure-Java.

Answer (score 2):

Some implementations have native libraries that boosts their performance They are usually optional but it is recommended to use them in production.

1. [JBoss](http://jbossweb.jboss.org/native)
2. [WebLogic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/perform/WLSTuning.html)
3. [TomEE](http://tomcat.apache.org/native-doc/) (based on Tomcat)